# Algebraic integers whose matrix representations have singular values in an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathcal{O}(K)$ be the ring of integers of $K$.  Let $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$ be an integral basis for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For each $a \in K$, multiplication by $a$ is a linear map from $K$ to $K$. Let $M_a$ be matrix for this map with respect to the given basis.

Let $A_R$ be the set of all $a \in \mathcal{O}(K)$ such that every singular value $\sigma$ of $M_a$ lies in the interval $(R,2R]$. (The singular values of $M_a$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $M_a^T M_a$.)

**Question** Is true that 
$$
\frac{R^n}{|A_R|} \leq R^{o(1)}
$$
as $R \to \infty$?

Some obervations:

1. If $A_R$ is modified to require that the largest (rather than every) singular value of $M_a$ belongs to $(R,2R]$, then this is true. This is because the largest singular value is the induced $2$-norm of $M_a$, which is comparable to the $2$-norm $\|a\|_2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ of $a = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \omega_i$.
2. Suppose $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\omega_1=1$ and $\omega_2=\sqrt{2}$. If $a = x+y\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ then the singular values of matrices $M_a$ are easily computed to be 
   $$
   \sigma_{\pm} = \sqrt{\frac{2x^2+5y^2 \pm \sqrt{9x^4+36x^2y^2}}{2}}. 
   $$
   So the question reduces to asking for a lower bound on the number
   of solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ to the inequality 
   $$
   N \leq \sigma_{-}  \leq \sigma_{+} \leq 2N
   $$
   (In this way, the question can be viewed as some kind of generalization of the Gauss circle problem.) I have not even been able to resolve this case.